# How do I use an object method in PDO::FETCH_FUNC

Tags: php, pdo, callback

This question references the following 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php
from the PHP manual.

This enables me to pass a function to process the result of a query before I get it.

I would like to pass as the function a method in an object.

Say the object is referenced by `$this` How would I write it?

Comment: See [Callbacks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are working outside of the class scope. You can do this

```
// SELECT id, title FROM pages

$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_FUNC, array('Foo', 'bar'));

Class Foo {
public function bar($id, $name) { return $id . " : " . $name;}
}
```

The same goes for using $this really

```
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_FUNC, array($this, 'bar'));
```